# Azure DevOps how to replacing values in Cloud.xml parameter of service fabric project at the time of release which are kept as variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I have Service fabric project and all configs like connection String and Keys are parameter under Application Parameter

/ApplicationParameters/Cloud.xml

```
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Web1_InstanceCount" Value="-1" />
    <Parameter Name="Web1_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value="Dev" />
    <Parameter Name="DbConnectionstring" Value="MyConnectionString" />
  </Parameters>
```

I would not like to store these values in the file but store them as Variables as Secret type. In the Release definition just before it is deployed I would like a step to replace these values.

Is there a task available to help me with replacing the values which are there in Variable section into the xml or do I have to write some form of custom script?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Service Fabric Application Deployment task, there is a checkbox "Override Application Parameters" which will do exactly what you want. Make sure variable name in DevOps and xml is the same and it will be overwritten.
[image]

Comment: What is the format for overriding application parameters? I can't get it to work using `SomeParameter=$(parameter_stored_in_devops_variable_group)`